# Incorrect page number in MS word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

In MS word the page sequence is coming  incorrect.There are total of 90 pages in the MS word these 90 page are divided in 10 letters (So the page number are from 1 to 9 for each letter) Each letter is separate by section break and each have a Table in it.

In one scenario when the macro runs .There are only two pages generated for each letter .

**First page numbering- Page 1 of 3**(this is incorrect ,it should be Page 1 of 2)

**Second page numbering -Page 2 of 2**

I am not able get a exact reason  for this issue.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Could you post a sample of the Macro code that produces the shorter? If you do that, you might want to tag the question with VBA so people with the correct expertise can help.

Comment: Thanks Owen. I wnt be able to share the Macro code unfortunately. The page number  is controll by MS word itself not from the vba code.So I am hoping  to get a clue on formatting or setting in MS word.

Comment: How do you add page numbers? The total number of pages entered manually or automatically generated?You can try to get the current number of pages again in the portion of the total number of pages